# Pods don't communicate between each other when on different nodes (EKS)

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

we have an EKS cluster with 4 nodes and 10 microservices (at this moment) on it. We used to have 2 nodes and didn't see much problems, but since increasing to 4, things have "randomly" stopped working. I believe that the pod of a node can not talk to another node of the cluster.

We have randomly "service unavailable" when the pods are not on the same node. When on the same node, it's all good. We use http://service.namespace:port in appsettings.

I thought Kubernetes would resolve this automatically? We have an EKS v1.12. Thanks

PS: We tried to "telnet IP port" and it worked from one of the pod. When we do http://service.namespace:port, it doesn't resolve.

Comment: are the new nodes in the same subnet of the old ones?

Comment: try `service.namespace.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi I just tried and we get this error: "error": "An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set." The devs are using c#

Comment: I am assuming that you are using coredns in EKS, could you please add the output of `kubectl get configmap coredns -n kube-system -o yaml`

Comment: could you please use just `http://service:port` if both the services are in the same namespace

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi funnily enough, we did ```http://service.namespace.svc.cluster.local``` and it seems like it is accepted. However, with both (so the long one and ```http://service:port```), we get an "error": "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Then it should be an issue with code validation! let me answer this question

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi That's what I assumed too. But looking at the code, we deployed version a, everything was all right. We deployed version b, which didn't change any .cs, and it is returning this error... Although there isn't really any code change? (thanks for all the help!)

Comment: We think maybe it is a very general error that is returned...? As in : 500 input string not in a correct format seems a bit weird? 500 are usually server issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the services are in the same namespace you can use `http://servicename:port`

If they are in different namespaces then you can use FQDN `http://servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local:port`